# angular material ie11 fix nested layout column overflow double scroll bar

Tags: angularjs, layout, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, angularjs-material

[the double scroll bar in ie11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKf5K.png) Facing particular issue in ie11 where the content of the container is overflowing the height of the container and ERGO the double scroll bar is observed in the ie 11 browser, i have tried fixing the issues by issue `flex-basis= auto` but that is not respecting the value, as there is nested layout column in the code, is there any workaround for it. for this issue

where there are nested layout column and flex-basis: auto is not working in ie11

Answer (score 1):

The Solution to this was to use `overflow: visible` in a class and use the same class in the html element. there was also a instance where `height: auto !important` also fixed the issue but layout-fill used in the code was not working properly after that